# Temperature excursion energy on Mars

Tags: temperature, gas

Could we use the high range of temperature excursion on Mars, for example applied on gases or liquids, to produce some usable energy?
Let's assume that the day-night excursion is +20 Celsius (day) and -100 Celsius (night).
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle the temperature differences could be used to produce energy. If you had some suitable thermal reservoir then heat would flow into it during the day and flow out of it during the night, and the heat flow could be used to do work.

In practice the amount of work you could get out would be too small to be worth the effort. The problem is that while it's true the atmosphere temperature on Mars changes by 120°C or so, that atmosphere is very thin so it has a very low heat capacity. It would not heat your reservoir very much during the day nor cool it very much during the night. Since the amount of heat flowing into and out of the reservoir would be small the work you could extract would also be small.

Comment: Thank you John. What if we use another substance that is not the martian air, such as an element that boils, let's say, at about -60 degrees. Would it change something? And what if we use the vapour of a boiling substance in that low pressure, just like we do with boiling water on Earth, would it be useful to produce some energy?

Comment: @Bea it's the air temperature on Mars that swings so violently. The temperature of the rock or other stuff on the surface doesn't change anything like as much. So a tank of your volatile substance wouldn't change temperature either.